# How to SIMPLY input hidden word in Python

Tags: python, string, hide

I'm a beginner and i'm going to create a simple Hangman game with Python. I'd like the player to input a word , but not to be shown on Python Shell and to be able to manipulate it as a variable.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For the future, please formulate a question, rather than just stating an intent and a thank you.  You will likely be better received.  Welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I think, the [getpass module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) might be what you're looking for.